# make axis2 to use specific return type

Tags: apache-axis

I am using an axis2 webservice, in which I am using following messageFormatter (org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter):

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
```

and following messageBuilder(org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder):

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>.
```

I have one element which I return as a String, Wsdl contract for which is as follows:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="totalCostStr" nillable="true" type="xs:String">
```

My problem here is when I receive the corresponding JSON and if totalCostStr is greater than 0.00, I am getting totalCostStr at client side in JSON as a string "0.00"

and when value totalCostStr is greater than 0, I get value at client side, in JSON as float (e.g. 12.65) and not as a string "12.65".

Is there a way to force axis to return totalCostStr as a Float or String always??

Thanks in advance,
Chetan

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange behaviour :/

You can for to use always as float using the type float in wsdl element

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="totalCostStr" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
```

This should work...